# TypeScript compiler doesn't complain if a getter is not implemented on a class that inherit a mixin abstract class

Tags: typescript

Edit:
Following the comment from @artur-grzesiak below, We've modified the playground for a simpler version, without a badly named `interface` method. where we would still expect the compiler to throw an error for the not implemented `getInterface`, but it does not do so:

[New playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-OwJCMErMHo+PapiT9ingn6DHr-QGTfoUnLonhYyh6AzGMwWaz2Vf7g8DaAkFg4-S6QwmOxr++gam03QYIY5HfaArAABhsf8hi5e9Y25Nd8gIEgiCwMdjnGJoR12U0cHNYgA0LetUxLLMcwwbRiN1GJ9U8P08OkPs71ADwYUWFj4RtdptDscwaJw-1bwGDxPlhJCsHJHIhPvBlzAAIipZgShKHAZNtNdJIPADt1AGSADFhXdZgVLUsA4MYjweSAA)

---

```
type GConstructor<T = {}> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;

// Raw objects interfaces
interface IBaseDataObject {
    readonly id: string;
}
// Name Pattern
interface Name {
    name: string;
}

// interfaces that classes must implement
interface BaseDataObjectInterface<T extends IBaseDataObject> {
    readonly id: string;
    readonly interface: T;
}

abstract class AbstractBaseObject<T extends IBaseDataObject> {
    readonly id: string;
    abstract readonly interface: T

    constructor(
        iBaseDataObject: T
    ) {
        this.id = iBaseDataObject.id;
    }
}

type AbstractBaseObjectCtor<T extends IBaseDataObject> = GConstructor<AbstractBaseObject<T>>;

// Country interface, class and instances
interface ICountry extends IBaseDataObject, Name {}

function NameAbstractMixin<TBase extends AbstractBaseObjectCtor<T>, T extends IBaseDataObject & Name>(Base: TBase) {
    abstract class NamedBase extends Base implements Name {
        readonly name: string;

        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args)
            this.name = args[0].name;
        }

    }
    return NamedBase;
}


class Country extends NameAbstractMixin(AbstractBaseObject<ICountry>) implements BaseDataObjectInterface<ICountry> {
    // get interface(): ICountry {
    //     return {
    //         id : "hello",
    //         name: "France",
    //     }
    // }
}
```

Country Class should enforce the abstract contract inherited from the `AbstractBaseObject` Class which declares an abstract property `interface` and the Class `Country` should implements `BaseDataObjectInterface` which requires the same property/accessor but typescript compiler doesn't raise any error as you can see on this typescript playground.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=54&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gwgewHYGdgCcCuBjYD0A8AKlALxQDeAvgHxlQCGARmug7lEhAO5QAUAOiEN0AcxQAuRkhABtALoBKMnSIBuALAAobQHpdUAEoNeCJgCsIuFFACWSYBHQAzdhBTb7jl26gBJACEGFAgAEQZgBgB5CytgSm0oJKh0CAYAE2QAGxA7dKlWe1FNLSo9AwA5BgBbaAAFCO8kTwcnV2xoKtqErWTOGogCjCKSsp0tfTtWnw6bYAALCKhsLOCQm2rMNDtqsCyIWocW73boIJDwyJjLXD9p0+IoCAAPRyR0m0DgsIjo2Nw6BREslUhlsrlbPkoIUkMVgUlQZkkDkpic3FJ1NoxtpmKx2PEVmsoABBFgYfHnCDXOKPF5vD7+SmXP43YCA+EpNJIlGQoboEYc3HkjiI8GotroqBEbQc7DIVg4PDoPgcvq2Jm-am4DEc5RA3p9ZILWwoASQ+jq77MrXAM3pEp9MbYrSgSAkslsXCUm1wJW014Qd6fDVXf5s+jweUYRX4AikvFe7424g0GglcpQRCYBzoCH3NwAGmWqxQNgY7ymaHLs2OEo6-izOdydMDDK+F01YaLXWg1BlWmc2dwtmQUB78eFwAAsrZnvZiJSngGg+6E8BvWHfbGiDQiyQWyv2z9Q6yoAAyMcDGh8SkYyl6wUe-HFok99KLg8Mxe2Xb7Q7AGwex6Q0QS5MUkAGPkBXGECkjlVBo1wfBBGEMRJGkOQlGA2C+hQTBIGVIQBBEcRFFVWDjVNCDunIEiUFkAAGeQBGoiAHVg51HQ5VJgEwdAkEvWp32+UZ+0JUtMwQbMMGbZcGXHJ9cBnOckD4CdPXXJMwwIPxGxkmhlB-PYDkDACoBDFk4juNEOh0vTc3ZA0kkmUQIHiLw6wgPhFCkXSpKbbDnIMPoeL4gT9T6SYcPNKQACJ5ggLIsgQWKCw5KLYNYuKADE2CQDpUvS4LkjGSKDCdIA)

Am I missing something here?

Comment: @toyotaSupra you have the code as text in the post + a playground. And the problem is that the compiler MUST return an error and doesn't.

Comment: @Jean-Xavier Raynaud. My apologized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove everything not related to the error itself, the problem will simplify to this:

```
type GConstructor<T = {}> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
type ICountry = 'ICountry' | 'IAnotherCountry'

abstract class AGetInterface<T> {
    abstract readonly getValue: T
}

function NameAbstractMixin1<TBase extends GConstructor<AGetInterface<T>>, T>(Base: TBase) {
    abstract class NamedBase extends Base { }
    return NamedBase;
}

class Country1 extends NameAbstractMixin1(AGetInterface<ICountry>) {
    // get getValue(): ICountry {
    //     return 'ICountry';
    // }
}
```

Let's try to verbosely add the types compiler should guess:

```
// Non-abstract class 'Country' does not implement inherited abstract member
class Country2 extends NameAbstractMixin1<GConstructor<AGetInterface<ICountry>>, ICountry>(AGetInterface<ICountry>) {
    // get getValue(): ICountry {
    //     return 'ICountry';
    // }
}
```

So here's the reason, compiler could not guess the type

Let's try to help compiler to guess the type correctly

```
type GuessType3<C> = C extends GConstructor<AGetInterface<infer T>> ? T : never;

function NameAbstractMixin3<TBase extends GConstructor<AGetInterface<T>>, T = GuessType3<TBase>>(Base: TBase) {
    abstract class NamedBase extends Base { }
    return NamedBase;
}
// Non-abstract class 'Country3' does not implement inherited abstract member 'getValue'
class Country3 extends NameAbstractMixin3(AGetInterface<ICountry>) { }
```

Now check if it works in initial code

```
type GuessType<TBase> = TBase extends AbstractBaseObjectCtor<infer T> ? T : never
function NameAbstractMixin<TBase extends AbstractBaseObjectCtor<T>, T extends IBaseDataObject & Name = GuessType<TBase>>(Base: TBase) { ... }
// Non-abstract class 'Country' does not implement inherited abstract member 'getInterface'
class Country extends NameAbstractMixin(AbstractBaseObject<ICountry>) { ... }
```

It does

---

Generally in such cases try to provide some type parameter out of the box,

```
function NameAbstractMixin4<T>() {
    return function <TBase extends GConstructor<AGetInterface<T>>>(Base: TBase) {
        abstract class NamedBase extends Base { }
        return NamedBase;
    }
}
// Non-abstract class 'Country4' does not implement inherited abstract member 'getValue' 
class Country4 extends NameAbstractMixin4<ICountry>()(AGetInterface<ICountry>) { }
```

works perfectly as is for example

---

I didn't know you could put T type parameter after its usage until now BTW

If you know how to split off a type parameter without double function please comment, I was looking for that